MYSQL GROUP BY most frequent value for each ID
I have following 2 tables: Sales and Menu.
SALES TABLE



customer_id
product_id




A
1


A
2


A
2


A
3


A
3


A
3


B
1


B
1


B
3


B
3


B
2


B
2


C
3


C
3


C
3



MENU TABLE



product_id
product_name




1
sushi


2
curry


3
ramen



**My problem statement is : **
Which item was the most popular for each customer.
So I am expecting the following output.



customer_id
product_name




A
ramen


B
sushi


C
ramen



I have tried the following query :
SELECT s.customer_id, m.product_name,
       (SELECT count(s.product_id) as freq
        from sales
        GROUP BY product_id
        ORDER BY freq DESC
        LIMIT 1) as maxFreq
from sales s
INNER JOIN menu m
  ON s.product_id = m.product_id
GROUP BY s.customer_id, s.product_id;

I can not apply group by on maxfreq because it is an inner query. Otherwise my work would be done.

A select-list subquery is typically correlated.

What yor MySQL version? Since MySQL * you can use window function for this

How did customer B return Sushi when all three menu have the same count?

We can take the first one from the three. @FanoFN

With MySQL supported version (v8 and above), you can try this:
SELECT customer_id, product_name
  FROM
(SELECT customer_id, product_name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY COUNT(product_name) DESC) AS Rn
  FROM Sales s JOIN Menu m ON s.product_id=m.product_id
  GROUP BY customer_id, product_name) v
WHERE Rn=1;

By using ROW_NUMBER() order by count descending of menu appearing for each customer.
Here's an alternative solution for older MySQL version:
SELECT customer_id, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(product_name ORDER BY f DESC, product_id),',',1) AS product_name
FROM
(SELECT customer_id, product_name, COUNT(product_name) AS f, m.product_id
  FROM Sales s JOIN Menu m ON s.product_id=m.product_id
  GROUP BY customer_id, product_name, m.product_id) v
GROUP BY customer_id;

The count is done in the subquery then using GROUP_CONCAT() with order by count descending and product_id ascending for similar menu with similar count. After that, using SUBSTRING_INDEX() to return the first value from the GROUP_CONCAT() identifying the comma as delimiter.
Here's a demo fiddle

You may use a ranking query to rank products for each customer using the ROW_NUMBER() function then extract rank=1 from the result to achieve the desired result. With this query you may also find rank 2 etc. by updating 1 to 2 etc.
SELECT customer_id, product_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.customer_id, 
        m.product_name,
        COUNT(s.product_id) AS freq,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY s.customer_id ORDER BY COUNT(s.product_id) DESC) AS ranking
    FROM sales s
    INNER JOIN menu m 
    ON s.product_id = m.product_id
    GROUP BY s.customer_id, s.product_id
) AS ranked
WHERE ranking = 1


(After receiving the comments):

If you are using MySql with older version than 8.0 the PARTITION BY is not available. Then use this instead:
SELECT s.customer_id, m.product_name
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN menu m ON s.product_id = m.product_id
WHERE 
    (s.customer_id, s.product_id) IN (
        SELECT s1.customer_id, s1.product_id
        FROM sales s1
        GROUP BY 
            s1.customer_id, s1.product_id
        HAVING 
            COUNT(s1.product_id) = (
                SELECT MAX(freq) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                        s2.customer_id, 
                        s2.product_id, 
                        COUNT(s2.product_id) AS freq
                    FROM sales s2
                    GROUP BY s2.customer_id, s2.product_id
                    ) 
                WHERE customer_id = s1.customer_id
            )
    )


rank is a reserved keyword.  COUNT(s.product_id) AS freq, is excess since it is not used anywhere

I am getting an error in PARTITION BY clause syntax error.

@ErgestBasha Thank you I updated the word rank to ranking.

@FarhaMansuri PARTITION BY is available on mysql 8.0 and later. Check my new answer for older versions.

This is not the correct output. It is not working.

What is the output? Do you receive error or wrong output? @FarhaMansuri

Using simple max and sum
select
       max(c.cnt) freq
       ,p.product_name
       from ( select count(product_id) cnt ,product_id from customer
       group by customer_id , product_id ) c
       inner join product p on p.product_id=c.product_id
group by p.product_name;


This is not working.
